What is the usage of vhadd_s8 in Neon intrinsics?
I think the behaviors of narrowing addition are quite strange. For example, int8x8_t vhadd_s8(int8x8_t a, int8x8_t b):

Signed Halving Add. This instruction adds corresponding signed integer values from the two source SIMD&FP registers, shifts each result right one bit, places the results into a vector, and writes the vector to the destination SIMD&FP register.

Can anyone explain its usage scenario?  The following is an example in Rust:
    let a_v: Vec<i8> = vec![8; 8];
    let b_v: Vec<i8> = vec![1; 8];
    unsafe {
        let a = vld1_s8(a_v.as_ptr());
        let b = vld1_s8(b_v.as_ptr());
        let c = vhadd_s8(a, b);
        println!("{:?}", c);
    }

Shift 8 right one bit becomes 4, and Shift 1 right one bit becomes 0. So the result is all 4. In which scenario, users would expect such 4 as the result?

A halving add is one way of computing an average. Rich instruction sets tend to offer multiple variants of averaging, e.g. averaging with truncation (a+b)/2 and averaging with rounding (a+b+1)/2. There are use cases for both flavors of averaging.

It calculates the mean average of the values in two arrays. I could see that being used for things like missing value interpolation for example.

Or if you want to calculate an average of n values, you could use this to calculate the average of 2^n length blocks and then average those.

Remember that a right shift of one bit is division by 2 (rounding toward minus infinity).  So this adds the inputs and divides the result by 2 - that is, it averages the inputs (arithmetic mean).
Regarding your example: note that the instruction does the addition first and then shifts the result, rather than shifting first and then adding as in your example.  So if the inputs are 8 and 1, they are first added to give 9, then shifted to give 4.  Indeed, the mathematical average of 8 and 1 is 4.5, which then rounds down to 4.
This instruction actually does a little better than simply combining an 8-bit add and a shift instruction, in that it ensure the addition doesn't overflow (presumably by keeping a 9-bit result for the addition internally).  Suppose the inputs were 100 and 110.  This instruction would give the mathematically correct answer of 105.  However, if you do an 8-bit add by itself, it will overflow, giving a result of -46; if you shift this, you get -23.
(If the shift was done first, as you had it in your example, it would avoid overflow, but also give less accurate results.  For instance, suppose the inputs were 5 and 9.  If we shifted first, we would get 2 and 4, whose sum is 6.  But the mathematical average of 5 and 9 is actually 7, and this is what we get if we add first and then shift.)
